# changing Part Of Speech to dictionary

Tags: python, nltk

I have this fuction that use NLTK to preduce PART OF SPEECH from given text and zip them in pairs after replacing cammas between each word and its part of speech with colons but i have an error in regex that i couldnt understand. please help me to correct my fuction. 
this is my fuction:

```
 def getTokenss(tweet):
       poses = []

       words = tweet.split()
       for i in nltk.pos_tag(words):
            re.sub(r",", ":", j)

            poses.append(i)
            pos_pairs = map(list,zip(poses[:-1], poses[1:]))


      return pos_pairs
```

and this the error i got:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\posTag.py", line 112, in <module>
      b =getTokenss(t)
    File "D:\posTag.py", line 94, in getTokenss
      j =re.sub(r",", ":", j)
    File "c:\program files\python27\lib\re.py", line 151, in sub
      return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
 TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `nltk.pos_tag` returns a list of tuples where each tuple consists of a particular word and its associated tag. That's why you are getting that error since `re.sub` expects a string as its third argument.

Depending on your usage, you might want to iterate over the result of `nltk.pos_tag` as:

```
for (word, tag) in nltk.pos_tag(words):
    #in case you want to merge the word and tag into a single string
    item = '%s:%s' % (word, tag)
    poses.append(item)
```

Also, the statement `pos_pairs = map(list,zip(poses[:-1], poses[1:]))` should be most likely placed outside of the `for` loop.

Finally, if you are dealing with tweets, I would recommend the [TweetTokenizer](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) which will perform much better than just the `split` method...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it work fine but i want the output be like this example:  ['After:IN', 'generating:VBG'] to ['After':'IN', 'generating':'VBG'] which look like a dictionary where the word is the key and the tag is the value

Comment: @IbrahimDangou if I understand correctly, then it should be sufficient just to use, .e.g., `item = "'%s':'%s'" % (word, tag)`?

Comment: THAT IS IT, THANKS, WORKING FINE

Answer (score 0):

there is a `j` variable calling `re.sub(r",", ":", j)` in your code with no reference.